# Quote not displaying properly

Tags: php, html, character-encoding

So the characters “ and ” (`&#8220;` and `&#8221;` respectively) are variations of the neutral quote (").  I see them in a data sheet I have that is full of html and am trying to find and replace them using php.

First, I am testing to see how to reproduce it.  Here is my php code:

```
<?php
echo chr(8220);
?>
```

Why doesn't this work?  I have tried other numbers in the `char()` function and it worked fine.  I have tried setting the character set to `UTF-8` and `ISO-8859-1` but it didn't work.  How do I make this echo the quote?

I am trying to echo it because I am trying to integrate it into the php code.  I know I can just copy and paste it but that will be too confusing to me.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the quotes?  Escape, delete, or replace?  There are functions for all 3.

Comment: @kyle replace.  I need the actual character, and as far as I know, you have to use the actual character in regex.

Comment: If you just want to replace it, have you tried `str_replace("&#8220;", $replaceWithWhat, $dataWithThatCharacter);`.  That will replace all instances of the quote with what you want.

Comment: html_entity_decode I just found works.  Thanks for your help, @kyle

Comment: As many have said before me, there are many ways to skin a cat.  Haha.  Glad you found a way.

Comment: My system (WinXP) *used* to display this "right double-quote" correctly, but for some reason it doesn't any more. Is it something to do with installed fonts? Or the particular font being used by my browser? I was using EI8, but switched to Chrome **after** it stopped displaying correctly, and it still doesn't work under Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$str = str_replace(chr(147), '"', $str);    // left double quote
$str = str_replace(chr(148), '"', $str);    // right double quote
```

Where `147` and `148` respectively equal left and right double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

[`chr()`](http://php.net/chr) will output only [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) characters.
Use `echo chr(34)`. 34 is decimal number for double quote in ASCII table. There is only 128 (0-127) characters in standard ASCII table. PHP support extended ASCII with 256 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the function [mb_convert_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php)?

See [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php#88611) explanation on the php docs for how to get the character from its html encoding. Here is the function that that person defined (directly copied from that link):

```
function unichr($u) {
    return mb_convert_encoding('&#' . intval($u) . ';', 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `charset=WINDOWS-1252"`

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=WINDOWS-1252" >
```